# NDK build for target x86_64 results in error

Tags: android-ndk, x86-64

I have set my NDK build Application.mk configured to do build for target x86_64 with APP_ABI configured as below
 APP_ABI := x86_64

When I run the NDK build with this, I get error as we below:
Android NDK: NDK Application 'local' targets unknown ABI(s): x86_64
Android NDK: Please APP_ABI definition in Application.mk

I am running the build on Linux x86_64 machine. Any suggestions on fixing this? Do I need to do some settings/configure NDK to do builds for x86_64.

Answer (score 9):

See [CPU-X86-64 doc](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/x86-64.html)

<s>Your setting is **x86-64**. Minus, not underscore.</s>

Note that you need to pull this TBD version from git, the published release as of today July 2, is still r9d with no 64-bit support.

**Update 2014/07/18**

Now that NDK r10 is out, the supported targets are:

```
APP_ABI=all32 is equivalent to APP_ABI=armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86,mips.
APP_ABI=all64 is equivalent to APP_ABI=arm64-v8a,x86_64,mips64.
```

You should specify API level L. You have to download the relevant NDK version from http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

The platform you're using doesn't support that targets, you must change your APP_PLATFORM (minimum is android-21 for 64bit support) or remove the unsupported ABI.
For example:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a mips  x86 
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
```

or

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a mips  x86 arm64-v8a x86_64 mips64
APP_PLATFORM := android-21
```